# NodeProperties in gds.alpha.shortestPath.stream

Tags: neo4j

The Neo4j Data Graph Science library has an Shortest Path algorithm (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/shortest-path/). The following sequence is the example algorithm which works for my project:

```
MATCH (start:Loc {name: 'A'}), (end:Loc {name: 'F'})
CALL gds.alpha.shortestPath.stream({
  nodeProjection: 'Loc',
  relationshipProjection: {
    ROAD: {
      type: 'ROAD',
      properties: 'cost',
      orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'
    }
  },
  startNode: start,
  endNode: end,
  relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost
```

The problem is that the graph has to be filtered before finding the shortest path. Every node has an attribute called *currentWeather* and every node with *currentWeather = "good"* is a valid node for the shortest path.

Is it possible to use e.g. the *nodeProperties* to filter for *currentWeather = "good"*?
And if that does not work, how would you create a subgraph or filter for nodes with *currentWeather = "good"*?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use cypher projection to filter the subgraph.

```
MATCH (start:Loc {name: 'A'}), (end:Loc {name: 'F'})
CALL gds.alpha.shortestPath.stream({
  nodeQuery: 'Match (l:Loc) Where l.currentWeather = 
        "Good" return id(l) as id',
    relationshipQuery: 'match (l:Loc)-[r:ROAD]-(t:Loc) return id(l) as source, id(t) as target, r.cost as cost',
     startNode: start,
     endNode: end,
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
  })
  YIELD nodeId, cost
   RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems with latest GDS version 1.17 +, shortestPath.stream has been discarded or replaced by different method name.

The same solution can be achieved by the `Dijkstra algorithm` as well which is in the Production stage in GDS.

// prepare cypher projection

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
         "myGraph", 
         "MATCH (n:Loc) WHERE n. currentWeather = 
        "Good" RETURN id(n) AS id", 
         "MATCH (n:Loc)-[r:ROAD]->(m:Loc) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS cost"
)
```

// Stream shortest path

```
MATCH (start:Loc {name: 'A'}), (end:Loc {name: 'F'})
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream(
        "myGraph", 
        {
           sourceNode: startNode, 
           targetNode: endNode, 
           relationshipWeightProperty: "cost"
        }
) 
YIELD index, sourceNode, targetNode, totalCost, nodeIds, costs, path
RETURN
    index,
    gds.util.asNode(sourceNode).name AS sourceNodeName,
    gds.util.asNode(targetNode).name AS targetNodeName,
    totalCost,
    [nodeId IN nodeIds | gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name] AS nodeNames,
    costs,
    nodes(path) as path
ORDER BY index
```

For more read about `Dijkstra` in GDS, read [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.7/algorithms/dijkstra-source-target/)